# Get a pointer pointer for a smart pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a smart pointer for an object, that I need to pass to a method, that only accepts a pointer pointer.

Here's an example, where the original smart pointer loses the ownership.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::unique_pointer<pcap_if_t> object;

    auto object_pointer = object.get();
    pcap_findalldevs(&object_pointer, ...); // The unique_ptr loses ownership after being passed to the function
}
```

How would I accomplish this, without the original smart pointer losing the pointer ownership?

**EDIT:**
The function I'm calling is *pcap_findalldevs* in libpcap. I'm afraid that the function might be the cause of losing ownership.
I have updated my code example to reflect the what I actually do.

Comment: As long as `some_function` doesn't take ownership of the pointer you pass it or the pointer its object points to what you're doing is probably just fine.

Comment: Using `std::move`, Have you tried it?

Comment: @Deleisha What exactly would you _move_ it to? Another `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: `get` does not transfer ownership. `release`, does.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious They will transfer the ownership accordingly

Comment: @Deleisha The question clearly states: "How would I accomplish this, **without** the **original smart pointer losing** the pointer **ownership**?" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I have updated the original question to further clarify what I'm trying to accomplish, and what I'm exactly doing.

Comment: Now you are in trouble, read the documentation of pcap_findalldevs  and you might even avoid unique_ptr (if memory is managed by that library)

Comment: It makes no sense to pass an address of a pointer that points to something to pcap_findalldevs. The function will overwrite the pointer.

Comment: @n.m. How would I properly get a smart pointer or should I simply use a normal pointer and pass that to libpcap?

Comment: Why is it ever a question? You *receive* a pointer from libpcap. It's an *output parameter*. Before the call it doesn't point to anything. After the call it points to a linked list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function which takes pointer to pointer usually does so because it might change it, and `pcap_findalldevs` is indeed does that. And that pointer should be released with call to `pcap_freealldevs`.

So your best bet is `unique_ptr` with custom deleter aquiring ownership from raw pointer:

```
struct pcap_deleter
{
    void operator()(pcap_if_t* ptr) 
    {
        pcap_freealldevs(ptr);
    }
};

//...
using pcap_ptr = std::unique_ptr<pcap_if_t, pcap_deleter> 
pcap_ptr get_devs() {
    pcap_if_t* object_pointer;
    pcap_findalldevs(&object_pointer, ...); 
    return pcap_ptr(object_pointer);
}

//...

auto object = get_devs();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Here's an example, where the original smart pointer loses the ownership.

Nope. The unique_ptr retains ownership after a call to `get()`

unique_ptr will lose ownership after a call to `release()`

reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of this. This is the correct calling sequence:

```
 pcap_if_t ip = nullptr;
 res = pcap_findalldevs(&ip, errbuf);
 // now ip (hopefully) points to something
```

There's no place for a smart pointer to anything *before* the call. Now *after* the call you can assign `ip` to some kind of smart pointer. Don't forget a custom deleter, you will need it.

Note that `ip` actually points to a linked list implemented with plain raw dumb honest pointers, which you cannot change. Utility of a smart pointer to the head of the list is questionable at best. It would probably make sense to copy the information to a suitable C++ container and dispose of the linked list right after the call.